# SOAP & REST Adapters

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, spring-boot

I was working an (SOAP service) application that was built using Spring Framework. In order to support multiple versions , we were using SOAP Adapters. The changes in actual implementation must be backward compatible & if any implementation level changes are required , we use the adapter version to have different functionality (but this is very rare).The advantage is that we just need to maintain a single code base and artifact.

We are planning to convert this into a REST application using Spring Boot. Can we have the same adapter implementation for REST services or should we look at having different code bases for different versions and also deploy multiple instances of the jar file?